# DNN7 module cannot debug due to break point not hit

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

When i using the Default DNN7 create modules (DotNetNuke Compiled Module), i want try to debug on Page_load

```
CustomModuleController objCustomModules = new CustomModuleController();
```

and make and breakpoint on the line, or anyline on Page_load, it given the error.

The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you check out the templates at http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com the templates in the visual studio starter kit frankly don't work.

That being said, if you want to make sure that the current template will work, check the following

1. What is the build location of the DLL (right click on the project, choose properties, check the build tab)
2. Do you have debugging enabled in the web.config file?
3. Are you building in DEBUG or RELEASE mode?

Answer (score 0):

What if you want to develop dynamic modules (non-compiled), in separate project, other than the website proj? 
The Christoc Templates are all compiled, right?